# XSD - allow only approved tags

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, restriction

I'm tring to find out if it's possible to restrict XSD validation to allow only tags that are specified in schema?
Let's say I have valid XML :

```
<root>
<a/>
<b/>
<c>
    <c1/>
</c>
<root/>
```

How could I prevent:

```
    <root>
<a/>
<b/>
<c>
   <c1/>
</c>
<c1/>
<root/>
```

or

```
<root>
<a/>
<b/>
<c>
    <c1/>
</c>
<BAD_TAG/>
<root/>
```

What I would really like is to be able to enforce strict check that will not allow tags other than specified (I've found something like enumeration but as I understand it only works with values?). But sufficient will be to be able to force my existing types to specify that they need parent and can't be just inserted werever developer wants.

Comment: Well, write a schema for the first document that defines the content of the root element as a sequence of the three elements `a`, `b`, `c` and then the others three samples are obviously not valid instances of the schema. It is not really clear where you think the problem is, as you haven't shown any schema.

Comment: aaaa.... I knew something was going on as no one else was having same issues. Looks like system was allowing those additional entries that it shouldn't because validation was done on final file composed from fragments and looks like all additional entries were just removed during preprocessing so they never reached final file (therefore even with error in source final xml was valid :D )

Answer (score 0):

Case closed. It wasn't a matter of XSD but preprocesing tools before XML was validated (they were removing uncompilant entries before validation and whole thing behaved like allowing tags outside of schema)